# Remove code snippets from the question summary if they appear before the actual question

Tags: feature-request

Some questions in Stack Overflow don't have a nice summary in some situations.  If the user adds a code snippet first and then the brief explanation, it will result in the following:

> [image]

---

But users expect a nice summary as below:

> [image]

to get a quick understanding of the question.

Can the summary be changed so it doesn't show the code snippet?

Comment: What exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: Even if the user put the code snippet first , in the question  the summery must be the explanation provided in the question.

Comment: Or, just maybe, the user should invest more effort into writing the question. That of course includes _not starting the question with a code dump_.

Comment: Why downvote ? Will you please elaborate ?

Comment: Feature requests can be downvoted to indicate "I don't think this feature will be useful". That might be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here really is a problem with the question. It should not start with a big block of code. So if you see such a summary, by all means edit the question to have a proper format. I think that's a far more useful approach in the long run.

Comment: There is no validation in the time of Question posting

Comment: That would be a different feature request though @DonChakkappan.